# How to add version to npm url dependency

Tags: npm

```
{
  "name": "consume_npm_pkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.2",
    "sample_npm_package": "https://github.com/nicolasxu/sample_npm_package.git",
    "mttest_npm_pkg": "git+https://NicolasXu999@bitbucket.org/medtouch/mttest_npm_pkg.git#v1.0.1"
  }
}
```

the mttest_npm_pkg will trigger an error because the way I specify version is wrong.

Here is the error message:

> npm install
>   npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 v1.0.1: fatal: ambiguous argument 'v1.0.1': unknown revision or path not in the work
>   ing tree.
>   npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 v1.0.1: Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 v1.0.1: 'git  [...] -- [...]'
>   npm ERR! git rev-list -n1 v1.0.1:
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Nxu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\
>   \bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v6.9.1
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
>   npm ERR! code 128
>   npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true rev-list -n1 v1.0.1
>   npm ERR! fatal: ambiguous argument 'v1.0.1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
>   npm ERR! Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
>   npm ERR! 'git  [...] -- [...]'
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
>   npm ERR!     https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\$projects\learn_package_managers\consume_npm_pkg\npm-debug.log

How do I correctly specify version for url dependency?

Comment: Anything after the `#` must match a git tag, commit, or branch name. Apparently, you don't have a tag named `v1.0.1`

Comment: @RyanZim "git tag" command in package directory shows "v1.0.1".  Does it mean my tag is v1.0.1?

Comment: Yes. Not sure what the issue is here. Try installing with the commit sha instead of the tag.

Comment: @RyanZim The problem is I didn't commit tag to server. By default, tag is not committed to server. Good lesson, thanks!